# How to split the jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I have a table and I need to get values for each row (in array), something like:
`[{1,'test'}, {2,'another test'}, {3, 'nothing'}]`, but the only I can get is:
`["1 test", "2 another test","3 nothing"]`. I need to send this values by ajax as json object ... and create another table - thus I need an array of values ...

```
var table = $("table");
var rowsAll = table.find("tbody tr");
rowsAll.each(function(i,l) {
    var rows = [];
    $(this).each(function(t,l){
    rows[rows.length] = cells[t]= $(this).text();
    return rows; //returns rows, but I need cells of each row
    }).serialize();//or get()
});
```

the html is something like this:

```
<table id="deal">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> num </th>
        <th> string </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr> <td> 1 </td> <td> test </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 2 </td> <td> another test </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 3 </td> <td> nothing </td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I really need help ...

Comment: There is no such construct in JavaScript as `{1,'test'}` - did you mean object `{1: 'test'}` or array `[1, 'test']`?

Comment: sorry .. I know only basics ... I just knew what I'd needed in server side :( jfriend00 already gave me the answer. Thnx anyway )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This form of data makes no sense as it's very hard to read with javascript:

```
[{1,'test'}, {2,'another test'}, {3, 'nothing'}]
```

I'm going to assume that what you want is this:

```
{"1": "test", "2": "another test", "3": "nothing"}
```

To get that second form, you could use this code:

```
var results = {};
$("#deal tbody tr").each(function() {
    var cols = $(this).find("td");
    results[$.trim(cols.eq(0).text())] = $.trim(cols.eq(1).text());
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WjgrC/.

Comment: Perfect! You were right about the format - is just that I didn't know how to ask  :) Thank you.